# In search of a mailing list app which can segment on location

Tags: mailing-list

I am searching for a mailing list webapp (think MailChimp) which is able to segment message recipients based on worldwide location, be that by post/ZIP code, town/city, country or less desirably (unless has a good API) on Latitude and Longitude.

I have been in contact with the aforementioned MailChimp, plus a few other hopefuls with no avail - MailChimp, although able to segment based on ZIP codes, only currently supports this for US addresses and I require worldwide.

Any suggestions for commercial (paid for but reasonable) or open-source (free) greatly appreciated.

**Update**:
Another service, activecampaign.com allows segmentation on location, however, only by where the user opens email. Another requirement is that I need to be able to segment on a given location (e.g. given by recipient at sign up).

Comment: Is it even possible based on the email protocol that we have?

Comment: Location segmentation? Nothing to do with protocol - database has email and location in: only send to emails with a location within a certain radius...

Comment: Do you have all the location data in your database?

Comment: @Wade Yes, the database contains: email, name, area, country.

Comment: Couldn't just about any email marketing software that has the ability to segment work for you then? Just segment your database into different lists and then MailChimp, AWeber, Campaign Monitor, ActiveCampaign, ExactTarget, GetResponse, ConstantContact, etc seem like they could all work.

Comment: Quite sad no one was able to answer. I wanted to try, but did not understand what location segmentation meant. @dav_i I hope you were successful in finding the answer yourself though...

Answer (score 0):

I would dump all of the recipient information into a Google Docs spreadsheet and write a quick mail merge script with the exact business logic required ([here's a tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) that would serve as a nice starting point).